# query with LIKE but case sensitive

Tags: android, sqlite

Why isn't my query case sensitive?

```
Select * from MyTable where name like '%Ann%'
```

shows record 1 correctly:

```
Record1= John, Ann, Jack
```

but shows also record 2:

```
Record2: Jack, Susanne, Jim
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could execute [`PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = on`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like), but this would affect all LIKEs used in your program, and disable any index optimizations for prefix searches.

A better idea would be to replace LIKE with [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name GLOB '*Ann*'
```

Answer (score -2):

the SQL LIKE is case-insensitive(thnks to CL ) So, on some SQL implementations you [can do case Sensitive SQL query Searches](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/)

check this too: [Case insensitive searching in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/case-insensitive-searching-in-oracle)

Comment: Is Sqlite caseinsensitive too?

Comment: LIKE is case insensitive as specified in the SQL standard. To change this default, you have to use a database-specific mechanism.

Answer (score -2):

[Copied from [rbedger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480401/11654):]

You can use the UPPER keyword on your case insensitive field then upper-case your like statement

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE caseSensitiveField like 'test%' 
AND UPPER(caseInsensitiveField) like 'G2%'
```

Comment: Using UPPER does not make the comparison case *sensitive*.