# sqlite3 - update query - case insensitive

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have used the following query for sqlite3 update.

```
UPDATE customer SET nameid = '0' where (a like '%aba%' or  b like '%aba%' or  c like '%aba%' or  d like '%aba%')  COLLATE NOCASE.
```

But In my tables, the respected column stores the value like ABA,Aba,ABa,aBA. I want to make update query with case insensitive. Kindly guide me , what mistake i have done.

The above query is not updating the tables.

THanks

Comment: use upper() or lower() to make case insensitive

Comment: `LIKE` is already case insensitive. Consider posting a more thorough example to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Hi Latto, LIKE is not working as case insensitive format. I am using the sqlite3 database in IOS. is there any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the followin query:

```
UPDATE customer SET nameid = '0' where (LOWER(a) like '%aba%' or LOWER(b) like '%aba%' or LOWER(c) like '%aba%' or LOWER(d) like '%aba%')
```

Here is the link for similar question:
[Case sensitive and insensitive like in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480319/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-like-in-sqlite)

Comment: Hi, I could not use Lower and upper case method. because the '%aba%' will receive from the server. Sometimes they will pass lower/upper/mixed. I want to check the characters alone not cases.

Comment: You can use LOWER in like as well: '... like LOWER('%abc%')'