# Ignore case in query to SQL database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I can't find a good example but if the name in the database is "namehascapsinit",  It doesn't return anything. Is there anyway to ignore case?

```
String selection = MyTable.COL_NAME + " = ?";
                        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ "NameHasCapsInIt" };
                        c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MyTable.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if you search "sqlite ignore case" here, you probably didn't have to ask this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480319/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-like-in-sqlite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE col_name COLLATE NOCASE ="namehascapsinit"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code like this

```
("select * from TableName where col_name collate latin1_swedish_ci =?",String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ "namehascapsinit" });
```

This is the example

```
select * from TableName where col_name collate latin1_swedish_ci ="namehascapsinit"
```

instead of latin1_swedish_ci you can use whatever collation you want

Comment: I'm getting errors "no such collation sequence: "latin1_swedish_ci"