# Compare strings ignoring case

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am trying to find entities (`Tag`s) in the database via their `Name` property, where it is important to ignore the case (When `database` is searched and the Database contains a Tag with the name `Database`, that one should be returned). Right now, my code looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<db.Tag> FindByNames(IEnumerable<string> tagNames)
{
    return this.DatabaseContext.Tags
        .Where(tag => tagNames.Contains(tag.Name));
}
```

Obviously, this one is case sensitive. I have tried to provide `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as comparer to the `Contains` method, but got a warning during execution that the expression could not be translated and would be executed in code rather than in the database (I don't remember the exact message, I will edit as soon as I am back on my development machine). I can live with that if I have to, but it would be nice to know how to let the database do the work in this case. Is it possible?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! Additionally, you might want to reconsider the `Contains`-operation, as this is going to be of linear (or worse) performance - If the  collection contains many elements, inserting in a temp-table with an index and doing a join might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

No change should be necessary. SQLite's "LIKE" is already case-insensitive.

> The default behavior of the LIKE operator is to ignore case for ASCII characters.

(cref https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like and [Case sensitive and insensitive like in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480319/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-like-in-sqlite))

Of course, you can always use `.FromSql()` to get the exact query you want. Example:

```
context.Tags.FromSql("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name LIKE '%{0}%'", tagName)
```