# Rails search users by first_name inside full_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have `User` model with attribute `full_name`. And I want users to search just by their first or last name.
I have tried

```
User.where("username= :username OR full_name LIKE :full_name", username: "rony", full_name: "rony")
```

But the problem is when I search with this only query, full_name will always return nill because this query only search exact "rony" in full_name instead of for example "rony sianturi", do you have any other suggestion in doing this query. Thank you.

I have search similar questions, but all other questions is the invese of this question. So no luck

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `like` with wildcard:

```
User.where("username = ? OR full_name like ?", "rony", "%rony%")
```

Comment: error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "ilike": syntax error: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username = 'rony' OR full_name ilike '%rony%') LIMIT ?`

Comment: @chronycles you are trying to retrieve records from sqlite not postgres, check my updated answer but this is case sensitive. If you need to check `full_name` with case insensitive, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480319/case-sensitive-and-insensitive-like-in-sqlite

Comment: I got this error since 'rony' string is inside a variable, how to remove the character (" ")? `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "%": syntax error: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username= 'rony' OR full_name= %'rony'%) LIMIT ?`

Comment: no worries, it works now. just a matter of syntax. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query with [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel). For example the search query here would be like

```
User.where(
  User.arel_table[:name].eq("#{key_word}").
    or(
      User.arel_table[:name].lower.matches("%#{key_word.downcase}%")
    )
)
```

Please check it out [Arel documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel) for more details & advanced queries.