# Can I create and call user-defined functions for SQLite from Java?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am manipulating a couple of SQLite files using Java. Is it possible to 
create a user-defined function for SQLite and use it in queries from Java? How 
to define such a function (e.g. power, exp) ?
I saw some related questions but could not understand how to use them.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192443/writing-user-defined-sql-functions-for-sqlite-using-java-or-groovy

Comment: Yes, thanks, I saw that but cannot unterstand how to do it in java

Comment: Which of the many Java SQLite drivers are you using?

Comment: The driver is frome here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc , latest vrrsion